# Retrieving file from temporary path after upload completes using AjaxFileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file, file-upload

I am using AjaxFileUpload on an asp.net page to upload files. I want to retrieve the file that is uploaded , from the temporary path on the server. I am able to get the temporary path that the control stores the data to using `Path.GetTempPath()` as mentioned in the documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx).

But the problem I am facing is that Ajax File Upload stores the documents in the following folder structure

```
Path.GetTempPath/_AjaxFileUpload/<GUID-looks like>/<actual file>
```

The GUID part changes when I use the control from a new tab ( new web session) on a browser.

I am not able to find the information on how to get this path to retrieve the file.
Please suggest if there is a way to access this folder structure so that I can access the file from the temp path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is you either save the path in a `Session variable` or in DB. So it's totally depends on how you want to use that path.

I use a Session to store a path after file upload complete and retrieve the URL when I want to confirm the changes, but if you need that path somewhere else on a new session you could store it into a file like an XML or even DB then use it in another place.

Here is a sample of how you do this using a Session variable:

```
protected void fileUpload_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "_AjaxFileUpload", e.FileId);

    //using session
    Session["FileDirectory"] = path;

    // you could also store this in db, xml or text file as well.

    // e.g. XML
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("Child", path)
        )
    );
    doc.Save("Root.xml");
}
```

And you can access your file path from the declared Session any where in your application.

**Extra Info**
Then you could just pass the file URL as a parameter to save your file in a new location anywhere from your application:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //get the file path from session, xml or db ..
     string filePath = Session["FileDirectory"].ToString();
     SaveFiles(filePath);
}

public void SaveFiles(string fileDirectory)
{
    //copy the file from temp serevr to the permanent folder
    File.Copy(fileDirectory, "your new path", false);

    //deletes the file from temp server
    Directory.Delete(fileDirectory, true);
}
```

Comment: I tried using sessions. Though they work, I can't use them in my specific situation due to the lack of session management. I am not sure of the details for now but I know I can't be using sessions :(

Comment: As I said if you cannot use Session then you could just store the path into the DB or a XML file instead. I've updated the answer with XML as well.